# API sima-land возвращает пустую страницу

Tags: php, curl

Пытаюсь получить данные в формате xml с API sima-land, но возвращает пустую страницу!

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('https://www.sima-land.ru/api/v2/category');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($curl); // сохранен xml
curl_close($curl);

$items = simplexml_load_string($xml);

print_r($items);
```

Comment: У вас `Ошибка загрузки XML `.

Comment: Опять же почему она возникает?

Comment: Так вам сервер не отдает данные, мне кажется.

Comment: У меня аналогичный код. но выдает ошибку 403 forbidden. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте установку опций

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

для отключения проверки SSL сертификатов.

Comment: Помогло! спасибо